# Rails partial update using a JSON object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, facebook

I am updating a partial by appending some facebook posts, which are fetched using koala gem. This is the code I've written. Here is the feed controller:

```
# feed_controller.rb

def index
end

def fb_feed
  @fb_feed = ..
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

This is the index view:

```
# index.html.haml

#feed-partial

:javascript

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "/facebook_feed",
      success: function(fb_feed){
        console.log(fb_feed);
      }});
  });
```

Facebook js file:

```
:plain
  $("#feed-partial").append("#{escape_javascript(render :partial =>'facebook', :locals => { :fb_feed => @fb_feed })}");
```

And the route:

```
get 'facebook_feed' => 'feed#facebook_feed', :defaults => { :format => 'js' }
```

Up till now everything works fine, but I want in ajax success to get a JSON object, and not a string. For that I've made some changes:

```
# feed_controller.rb

respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :json => @fb_feed }
end

# index.html.haml

...
$.ajax({ url: "/facebook_feed",
  dataType: 'json',
...
```

Now I am obtaining a JSON object, but the partial is not updating.
What I am missing, or what do I need to do, in order to render to partial the JSON object?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the partial not rendering? Or is the partial rendering but not displaying data from the object?

Comment: Can u show browser console log? I think you miss single quotes on append method in facebook js file

Comment: Adrian Mann, putting just some plain text into the partial, seemed that the partial is not rendering at all.

Comment: @SergeyGorlanov the console is actually giving me the JSON object.

Comment: @dimmg try to remove `{ render :json => @fb_feed }` u js partial not rendering

Comment: @SergeyGorlanov this way neither partial is rendering, nor the JSON object is received

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the partial and append it to page
You should respond with js format on ajax request. And by default was rendered %action_name%.js.erb(haml etc.)

If you want create html on javascript with data recived from controller, way with 
`{ render :json => @fb_feed }` will be right

If you want use both, you must declare 2 respond formats with js and json.